# vscode reopen always last session

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode (1.18) reopen always last session, i have set `"window.restoreWindows": "none"` but seems not work, my settings:

```
{
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "window.newWindowDimensions": "inherit",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Ubuntu mono",
    "editor.fontSize": 15,
    "workbench.editor.showTabs": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
    "window.restoreWindows": "none"
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"window.restoreWindows": "none" should work.

Unless you open a project from the right click context menu.

Comment: sorry, I missed a click, I wanted to accept the answer